# Reuse UIViewController instances when using storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I decided to give the use of storyboards a go in my current iPhone app. I am facing a bit of a problem. I really need to reuse my UIViewController instances.

What do I mean by that? Well, for example I have a table view controller. When I tap a cell, another view controller is loaded from the storyboard and pushed onto the navigation controller stack. This all works well, but it takes about half a second to a second each time this view controller is loaded. Before I was using story boards I simply solved this problem by caching the created instance so the second time you tap a cell the view controller can be immediately shown.

By caching the created instance I mean something like this:

```
if (!cachedInstance) {
    cachedInstance = [MyViewController new];
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cachedInstance];
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this using the storyboard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How were you caching them prior to storyboards?

Comment: I added an example to the question to clarify.

Comment: And now you are using segues I suppose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using segues, you will need to create custom segues in order to use a cached view controller like you did before.  Otherwise, the typical "push" segue will create a new instance of the view controller for `segue.destinationViewController`.  If you write a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` class and use `custom` `segue`s you can override `initWithIdentifier:source:destination:` and put your cached view controller in for the `destinationViewController`, and then override `perform` to use the classic `pushViewController` call.

That is how you handle the segue if you are really intent on using them.  I would just skip it though, unless you really want the fancy arrows to lay everything out on your storyboard.  If you skip it you can just instantiate the view controllers into the cache and then push them on just like you did before.

If your question is more about locating a view controller inside a storyboard then you can use:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Some View Controller"];
```

Then you can save that to your cache and push it like you did in your example code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! This week I will give the custom segue solution a try! It sounds like this is a good solution. I will accept your answer if it works!

Comment: I'm sorry but your solution won't work unfortunately... I can override that initWithIdentifier:source:destination: method but it already sends me a pre-constructed instance of the destination view controller! I want to prevent instantiation of that controller in the first place.

Comment: Your second suggestion works! I would rather have the "fancy arrow", but oh well at least it works.

Comment: You can use that to instantiate the controller and then set it up in a custom segue, it is just a lot of extra work just for the benefit of a nice layout.

Comment: The way I see it is: if I want to use storyboard, I should fully use it. Otherwise there is no point using it and it would be a better idea to use separate xib files.

Comment: by the way, 'ViewController *vc' should be 'UIViewController *vc'