# Transitioning between viewcontrollers without re-initializing them

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboard

I have two view controllers, one that shows some content in a list and one that renders a map. I give users the option to switch between the two by tapping a button. I'm currently using a segue for the button to switch between the two views, but because of the nature of segues I end up re-initializing the view controller each time, generating unnecessary network traffic.

I'm looking for a way to transition between these two views in such a way that the controllers are only initialized once, the first time they're invoked. Subsequent invocations of these controllers would just use whatever instance was already loaded in memory.

Is this achievable? If so, what do I use? pushViewController also ends up calling viewDidLoad on the controller being pushed onto the stack

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reuse UIViewController instances when using storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632740/reuse-uiviewcontroller-instances-when-using-storyboard)

Comment: Sounds like you may want to use a Tab Bar Controller, which is designed to coordinate multiple view controllers.

Comment: Our UI has a single view for data, that can be shown as a list or on a map so I don't the tab bar approach would work for us here. 

On caching the view controllers, I tried doing that and pushing the cached instance on to the stack. It works the first time, but since users can repeatedly switch between the two views I eventually run into a "Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported" exception. I tried looking at the top of the nav stack and seeing if I could just pop instead, but the top is the current controller, not the one I would want to pop to.

Comment: this works, would appreciate any feedback on whether it's poor form 



`NSArray* vcs = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    if ([vcs count] >= 2) {
        if ([[vcs objectAtIndex:[vcs count] - 2] isKindOfClass:[MapViewController class]]) {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }  else {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapVC animated:YES];
    }`